# Jmeter CSV Data Set Config to skip first row

Tags: jmeter, csv-file

I am trying to run HTTP request using JMeter with parameters inside .csv file and it is working as expected.

As i am using 8 different request, with different inputs, header would be really helpful.

The problem is that i don't know how to make Jmeter to skip first row while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config):

> Versions of JMeter after 2.3.4 support CSV files which have a header line defining the column names. To enable this, leave the "Variable Names" field empty. The correct delimiter must be provided.

Comment: i have additional question, i am fairly new in JMeter? Where can i see right version of JMeter? I am currently using 2.13, and this thing is working on this version as well. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Go to http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html and search for the word _version_.

Answer (score 0):

There is a field called "Ignore first line (only used if Variable Names is not empty)", set this to true.

[image]